# bootgrid using json data not loading php mysqli

Tags: php, json

I am trying to load the data into bootgrid along with two buttons edit and delete. but data is not loaded.what i tried so  far now i  attached the code below.how to load the data using json get_data.php page.can some one correct the code please.i tring this last 3 days. i couldn't get the result

**Table**

```
<table id="grid-basic" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="id" >Project Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="sender">Project Description</th>
        <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Project Client</th>
        <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 <script>
        var grid = $("#grid-basic").bootgrid({
            ajax: true,
            post: function ()
            {
                return {
                    id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
                };
            },
            url: "get_data.php",
            formatters: {
                "commands": function(column, row)
                {
                    return
                    "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></span></button> " +
                    "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></span></button>";
                }
            }
        }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
        {
            /* Executes after data is loaded and rendered */
            grid.find(".command-edit").on("click", function(e)
            {
                alert("You pressed edit on row: " + $(this).data("row-id"));
            }).end().find(".command-delete").on("click", function(e)
            {
                alert("You pressed delete on row: " + $(this).data("row-id"));
            });
        });
    //    $("#grid-basic").bootgrid();
    </script>
```

**get_data.php**

```
  <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crudphp");
$query ="SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY id DESC";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY id DESC ");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$project_name,$project_description,$project_client);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id,"project_name"=>$project_name,"project_description"=>$project_description,"project_client"=>$project_client);

        $output = $output[] = $output["current"] = 1; $output['rowCount'] = 10;

    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I think your `$output` should be wrap inside `rows`  also you are missing `rowCount` and `total` [here](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples)

Comment: rowCount and total how to write sir

Comment: make an array like `$output = []` `$output["row"] = your_data` `$ouput["total"] = your_row_count` `$output["current"] = 1` `$output['rowCount'] = 10` . rowCount and current is what your get from ajax so you could limit and offset data. [click the link then click on json response](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples)

Comment: $output[] = array ("id"=>$id,"project_name"=>$project_name,"project_description"=>$project_description,"project_client"=>$project_client); this data how to write sir.

Comment: get_data.php code i edited but data is not loaded why sir